# event id's 1030 & 1058. Can dir \\mail\sysvol but not dir \\domain.org\sysvol?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, group-policy, internal-dns

I'm running Win2003 Server 32 bit that also runs Windows DNS Server and Exchange Server.

I'm getting event id's of 1030 and 1058 every 5 minutes.

I was forced by my co-location provider to change ips (when the problem started) and the server is multi-homed (but only one NIC registers ips in DNS).

The email server may have become clogged with incoming emails, but ... I can't really talk to it properly to clear out the queues.

Typing DIR \domain.org\sysvol\ fails.

However, DIR \mail\sysvol succeeds, so Sysvol exists.

But, DIR \mail.domain.org\sysvol also fails..

Both mail.domain.org, domain.org, and mail map to the same ip address in dns.

I can ping all of them and see them with nslookup.

This seems to be some kind of simple name resolution problems, but ... I'm blind to the solution?

C:\WINDOWS\SYSVOL\sysvol exists.

gpotool.exe /verbose shows:
Domain: domain.org
Validating DCs...
mail.domain.org: down (sysvol only)
Error: DC list is empty

DcDiag SYSVOL tests passes??
      Starting test: frssysvol
         * The File Replication Service SYSVOL ready test
         File Replication Service's SYSVOL is ready

NET SHARE shows:
        SYSVOL       C:\WINDOWS\SYSVOL\sysvol        Logon server share

tried dfsutil /purgemupcache
dcdiag DnsBasic shows NO problems
DCdiag /test:DNS passed
DcDiag /test:frssysvol passed
DcDiag /c passed
DcDiag /v passed
dcdiag /test:netlogons passed

I compared netDiag.exe /debug to an Win2003 server where I can DIR DIR \domain.org\sysvol\ without issue, and there are no real differences.

nslookup
set type=all
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.org
Server:  localhost
Address:  127.0.0.1

_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.org     SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 389
          svr hostname   = mail.domain.org
mail.domain.org     internet address = xx.xx.xx.xx

I've tried:
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns

I believe DNS is working as it should, and all the entries I've looked at are what I expected to see,. and NSLOOKUP shows me what I expect to see.

But, the name resolution seems to have an issue, or dir \domain.name.in.full\sysvol would work?

I'm really stumped on this.  I've been researching this for a week, looking at issues others have had with 1030 and 1058, and learned more about tests to run than I ever wanted to know.

Microsoft won't even open a ticket for $$, as Win2003 is no longer supported.

Any ideas on the steps I can take to resolve this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have a look here for multiple things to try... http://terrytlslau.tls1.cc/2011/03/group-policy-and-account-is-not-dc.html

Comment: What will happen if I answer 'y' to dcgpofix?  I don't want to undo all the setup on the box.  There's only the single DC, it runs the Exchange email and the DNS.  I'd already restarted it many times.